# Jquery doesn't post for some reason

Tags: jquery, post

I wrote this small page and for some reason when I cilck on the submit nothing happens (checked on firebug, no submit is happening)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('form#login').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://my.site/login.php',
                data: this.html(data),
                success: success,
                dataType: dataType
            })

        });






    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="login">
        <input type="textbox" id="UserName" value="user">
        <input type="textbox" id="Password" value="password">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You should return `false` from the submit handler to avoid jumping. (And to avoid submitting twice if you change the action URL in the HTML to a real link, which you should do if you want the form to work without javascript.) And `$.post` is easier to use - `$.ajax` is for hand-crafted AJAX queries, you rarely need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your code to run on `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#login').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://my.site/login.php',
            data: this.html(data),
            success: success,
            dataType: dataType
        })

    });
});
```

Currently `$('form#login')` is running before the form is present in the page, so it's not finding anything to hook that submit handler to, making it wait to run until `document.ready` will fix this.  As for why you don't see anything happening in firebug, your *default* form action is currently happening, submitting to `#`, e.g. going nowhere...so no traffic for firebug to see.